# open office - How to make a click on a line in an index of a document take me to the paragraph itself?

Tags: openoffice

I am using OpenOffice 3.1.1
I have an index and I want that every click will take me to its paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index may be the wrong choice. An index might contain entries referring to several different pages, so the OpenOffice Index generation dialog doesn't use hyperlinks. Since you apparently have a one-to-one correspondence between index entries and paragraphs, I would generate a Table of Contents instead, title it "Index", generate it with hyperlinks and place it at the end of the document.

Here's a link to a tutorial on how to generate a [linked TOC](http://danilop.wordpress.com/2008/07/06/how-to-create-a-linked-index-with-openoffice/) (the author actually calls it an index)

The OpenOffice default is now to use `Ctrl-Left_click` to follow hyperlinks. If you want to change this to `Left_click` only, then on the main menu navigate Tools/Options/OpenOffice/Security and click the Options button in the Security and Options section and uncheck the Ctrl-click required to follow hyperlinks.

Comment: Worked. Took me a long time to understand this whole line structure marking but it finally works now thanks.